# How many times can you win a game with limited chances but increasing odds after a failure?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

I am stumped as to how to figure this out, so hoping someone way better at statistics and probability can help!

Say you have a game where you pay 1 coin for each attempt, and your odds of winning a prize on the first attempt are 2%.  If you fail, you can play again and the odds of winning go up to 8%.  If you continue to fail, your odds of winning continue to go up at the increments of 12%, 25%, 40%, 50%, 75%, and finally on the 8th try they would reach 100% and you would be guaranteed to win.

My question is, how many prizes could you expect to win if you had 100 coins to spend?

Edit: Yes, the odds go back to 2% each time you win.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: I would start by calculating the average number (expected value) of tries you need. It can be calculated by
$$
\mathbf{E} = 1\times P(\text{win on first try}) + 2 P(\text{win on second try} | \text{first try failed}) + 3 P(\text{win on third try} | \text{second and third try failed}) + \ldots
$$

Comment: As a nitpick, the words "odds" and "probability" both have similar implications however they are not defined the same way.  The *odds* of picking a heart out of a standard deck of cards is $1:3$ for (*or similarly $3:1$ against*).  The *probability* of doing so is $\frac{1}{4}$.  Do not mix up the words.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have a number of coins $c$ in your pocket. You can then play $c$ times, and the expected number of victory is $c$ times the chance of winning.

**I am supposing that when you win the price, your odds go back to 2% on the next attempt**

Denote $p = (0.02, 0.08, 0.12, 0.25, 0.40, 0.50, 0.75, 1)$

Furthermore, the number of tries before winning the price will be :

- $1$ with probability $q_1 = p_1$
- $i$ with probaility $q_i = (1-q_{i-1})*p_i$ for all $i \in {2,...,8}$

Indeed the maximum number of try before winning is 8 since on the 8th try you always win.

Denoting N this number of tries before winning (i.e $\mathbb{P}(N = i) = q_i \forall i$), the chance of winning is $\frac{1}{N}.

So the mean number of prize for each try is :

$$\sum\limits_{i} q_i \frac{1}{i}$$

Comment: Hi Irnv, seems like you’re on the right track, so what would the actual answer be given my scenario? I’m not that strong with math so I’m actually looking for the answer and maybe show the work for how you got it?  So if the number of coins = 100, how many prizes would I expect to have by the time my coins run out?

Comment: Sorry, i thought you were able to understand what i said. The formula to calculate your answer is clearly written in my comment. Just compute every variable in my calculations. 

Multiply the mean numer of prize by 100 if you have 100 coins